# findHomography function of OpenCV 3.0 RC1 in Java is not working

Tags: java, opencv

I want to calculate Homography of images using OpenCV in Java, but it throws Exception: `OpenCV Error: Bad argument (The input arrays should be 2D or 3D point sets) in cv::findHomography`

My code is like this (because the code is very long I just posted the part of code):

```
    ....
    List<Point> obj = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Point> scene = new ArrayList<>();

    KeyPoint[] _keypoints_object = keypoints_object.toArray();
    KeyPoint[] _keypoints_scene = keypoints_scene.toArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < good_matches.size(); i++) {
        obj.add(_keypoints_object[good_matches.get(i).queryIdx].pt);
        scene.add(_keypoints_scene[good_matches.get(i).trainIdx].pt);
    }

    MatOfPoint2f _obj = new MatOfPoint2f();
    _obj.fromList(obj);
    MatOfPoint2f _scene = new MatOfPoint2f();
    _scene.fromList(scene);

    **Mat H = Calib3d.findHomography(_obj, _scene, Calib3d.RANSAC, 3);**
    ....
```

No error during compiling, I have already declared a `2D Point` which is `MatOfPoint2f` and compiler is accepted, but when run the code it will throws the exception. What will be the reason, is this OpenCV bug or the code has problem?

If someone knows about please tell me how to solve. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: please try to print out your _obj and _scene Mat's

Comment: Yes I did that, the data was correct (Point2D), because when we create MatOfPoint2f from Points list then the data must be MatOfPoint2f also the compiler accepted, but when we run the program it throws the exception above, I don't know why it happens, if the data type not match then the compiler will not let the program to run.

Comment: i was hoping, you would find empty Mats (no matches found) at runtime..

Comment: Yes you are right, thank you! But why the line below gives me empty Mat
FeatureDetector detector = FeatureDetector.create(FeatureDetector.ORB);
  MatOfKeyPoint keypoints_object = new MatOfKeyPoint();
  MatOfKeyPoint keypoints_scene = new MatOfKeyPoint();
  
  Mat descriptors_object = new Mat(), descriptors_scene = new Mat();
   
  detector.detect(img_object, keypoints_object, descriptors_object);
  detector.detect(img_scene, keypoints_scene, descriptors_scene);

The both descriptors are empty. it is why? I tried ORB, FAST, but SURF  and SIFT are not supported.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (obj.isEmpty() || scene.isEmpty()) {
        LOGGER.debug("No matches found at all.....");

    }
```

The List of obj or scene will be empty.
try to avoid findHomography when the list is empty.

Comment: for finding the keypoints and descirptors , create an object for the FeatureDetector you want.
Ex: ORB object_name = ORB.create();

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please edit your question to add information; this is much more readable than putting together answer and comments.

Comment: i have not mentioned any questions in my answer

Comment: Sorry, I meant edit your answer instead of commenting it.